# Linux sed regex escape

Tags: linux, sed, regular-expression, xml

I use sed -i to replace the port value in a xml file,

```
<property name="port" value="8954" />
```

But I don't know how escape the regex, my regex is below.

```
(?<=name="port"\s+value=")\d+(?=")
```

my command is

```
sed -i "s/${PORTREX}/$NEWPORT/g" config.xml
```

Comment: regarding the regex you've tried, it won't work with `sed` because it doesn't support lookarounds and `\d` will match `d` instead of numbers.. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y for details

Comment: thx Archemar,  Sundeep, I will try other solutions.

Comment: What is the drawback of `"s/\(name=\"port\" *value=\"\)[0-9]*/\1$NEWPORT/g"`?

Comment: thx Philippos, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this in a comment because I didn't realize that this is already the solution. The OP wrote it works, so this time as an answer:

```
sed "s/\(name=\"port\" *value=\"\)[0-9]*/\1$NEWPORT/g" config.xml
```

The regular expression suggested by the OP used a couple of non-standard extensions, so it didn't work with `sed`, but you don't need them:

I use sed -i to replace the port value in a xml file,

But I don't know how escape the regex, my regex is below.

- instead of the "lookbehind" `(?<=somestring)` you can use the string as is, but it in `\(somestring\)` to mark it as subexpression and reuse it in the replacement as `\1`, thus instead of saying "this needs to be there, but not get replaced", just replace it with itself
- The `+` is a shortcut for `\{1,\}` (one or more occurences), but you can also replace `a+` with `aa*`. In this case it's probably save to use a simple `*`, because zero occurences are impossible
- The `\d` is not better to read than `[0-9]`, in my opinion
- `\s` can be replaced by `[[:space:]]` or `[ <literal tab>]`. Here a simple whitespace does the job

**Conclusion: Almost all reg-ex extensions can easily be avoided, maybe giving a little lengthy pattern or harder to read, but often without disadvantage.** An exception is the non-greedy match: In some cases you need a different concept without them.

Answer (score 1):

Using XMLStarlet on the XML document `file.xml` to update the value of the `value` attribute of all `property` nodes whose `name` attribute is `port`:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//property[@name="port"]/@value' -v "$NEWPORT" file.xml
```

The XPATH expression `//property[@name="port"]/@value` means "the `value` attribute belonging to any `property` node whose `name` attribute is `port`".  The selected attributes will be set to `$NEWPORT` (this is assumed to be a port number).

Example:

```
$ NEWPORT=8080
$ xmlstarlet ed -u '//property[@name="port"]/@value' -v "$NEWPORT" file.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <property name="port" value="8080"/>
</root>
```

Using `sed` to modify XML is difficult, especially if you're trying to use a Perl-like regular expression that `sed` simply does not support. Using line-oriented tools to process XML is also fraught with potential issues relating to the placement of newlines and the relative placement of node attributes within lines (note that `<property name="port" value="8954" />` is the same as `<property value="8954" name="port" />`).  Encoding of strings is also a potential issue that `sed` could handle *only if* you did proper decoding within `sed` itself (e.g. `&amp;` --> `&` etc.)

Question related to the difficulty of parsing XML-like data using regular expressions:

- [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
sed -i "s/name=\"port\" value=\"8954\"/$NEWPORT/g" config.xml
```